# Is ZonedDateTime hashCode() Consistent with isEqual()?

Tags: java, datetime, time, java-8, java-time

I am wondering if the implementation of `ZonedDateTime.hashCode()` is guaranteed to be consistent with [`ZonedDateTime.isEqual(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-)?  If not, then how can such a hash-code be computed?

**EDIT**

NOTE THAT THIS QUESTION IS ABOUT THE METHOD [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-), NOT ABOUT `equals`.  That is not a typographical error in my question.

**EDIT #2**

The reason I am asking this is because I have a class that contains a `ZonedDateTime` object.  The implementation of this class is as follows:

```
public class Foo {
    private ZonedDateTime dateTime;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        // Boilerplate stuff here...
        final Foo other = (Foo)obj;
        return (... && dateTime.isEqual(other.dateTime) && ...);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // What do I need to put here so that my implementation of
        // hashCode is consistent with my implementation of equals?
        return Objects.hashCode(..., dateTime.?, ...);
    }
}
```

As you can see by the implementation, I am calling the `isEqual` method within my implementation of `equals`, since I want two objects to compare equal when the stored times point to the same instant.  What can I put in my implementation of `hashCode`, such that the `Foo` class meets the requirement that `hashCode` be consistent with `equals`?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think otherwise? If it's the case, it should be properly documented.

Comment: You really need to explain why you think this might be the case.  Otherwise the question is likely off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @fge No, the language spec only guarantees that the `hashCode` method is consistent with `equals`.  I am asking if it is consistent with a different method, called [`isEqual`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#isEqual-java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime-), which produces a different result that `equals`.  They are two different questions.

Comment: @JimGarrison I don't understand why you feel I need to elaborate further.  I have not found any documentation whatsoever that makes me think this is guaranteed by the Java language spec.  If you have other information available to you, then please post it as an answer.

Comment: @fge there is an `isEqual` method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isEqual()` method javadoc says

> This is equivalent to using `dateTime1.toInstant().equals(dateTime2.toInstant());`.

So if you want to calculate a hashcode consistent with this method, you would have to use `zdt.toInstant().hashCode()`. Then your `Foo.hashCode()` would be consistent with your `Foo.equals()`.

Comment: Okay my upvote, but then the question arises why the OP operates with `ZonedDateTime` and not simply with `Instant`? ;-) Programmer life can probably be easier without `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: @MenoHochschild I want the public interface to be expressive.  When someone gets or sets a time, I want them to explicitly know/specify the timezone.  I also need to serialize the time to a string of the format "yyDDHHmmss" (with implicit UTC timezone).  As far as I can tell, there is no way to serialize/deserialize an instant without going through one of the DateTime classes.  So yes, I could store the Instant behind the scenes, but would have to convert it back and forth for both the public interface and serialization/deserialization.  Seems like a lot of extra work for very little benefit.

Comment: @JeffG Well, I admit that `ZonedDateTime` is not my personal preference because it has a strong tendency to make things more complex than they are (see also this whole question and answer stuff). As my experience shows, a combination of `Instant` and `ZoneId` is usually enough, here also enough for serialization to a date-time-string. You think it is not possible but it is - just set up a formatter with timezone information. And `ZonedDateTime` would also need such a formatter for the serialization (to JSON?). It is often more helpful to split complex things into several simple components.

Answer (score 2):

**About your question regarding the method `isEqual()`:**

This method has nothing to do with the `Object`-methods `equals()` and `hashCode()`. It should probably be better renamed to `isSimultaneous()` in order to avoid confusion and to make the instant-only comparison clearer. **Making a relationship of this similar-named method to consistency with `hashCode()` is pointless.**

Of course, if two `ZonedDateTime`-objects have the same instant then the comparison based on `isEqual()` will yield `true`, but the hash codes are often different due to different local timestamps. You might consider this as inconsistency of `hashCode()` with `isEqual()`, but that is not the point.

**The method `isEqual()` is simply not relevant in any context where you use a hashmap-lookup.**

In reverse, **the method `hashCode()` (or any computed hash-code) is not relevant if you use the method `isEqual()`**.

The reaction of so many downvoters (also my first misunderstanding of your question and your downvote shows that there is a lot of confusion potential in the fact that both methods (`equals()` and `isEqual()`) sound so similar but have very different meaning.

Comment: So I take it that your answer can be summarized as, "No, `hashCode` is NOT guaranteed to be consistent with `isEqual`".  Is that correct?

Comment: @JeffG I have edited my answer again. Don't look for any consistency of `hashCode()` with `isEqual()`. Is it clearer now for you?

Comment: "Making a relationship of this similar-named method to consistency with hashCode() is pointless."  It isn't pointless if I have a class that compares equal if the result of `a.isEqual(b)` is true.  In that case, for my class to follow the Java language requirements, I have to figure out a way to compute such a hash code.

Comment: @JeffG It is pointless because you use `hashCode()` only for hashmap-like structures. And these structures only use `equals()`, never `isEqual()`. Latter one is a completely independent comparison method and has nothing to do with `hashCode()`.

Comment: I think it is good enough to remove my downvote, but still doesn't address how to compute such a hash code.

Comment: @JeffG I cannot quite follow why you want to compute the hash code. I think the class `ZonedDateTime` does it for you. And if you use any kind of hash-based map then `equals()` will automatically be used. Can you please describe your use-case for a new hash computation?

Comment: I updated the question to illustrate why I need such a hash code method.

Comment: You need to be able to compute a hashCode that works in parallel with isEquals() for the following usage - 1) you have a container class that you want to be able to use with a ZonedDateTime field, along with several other fields 2) you want to be able to use this container class as a key in a map or as an item in a set 3) you want "isSimultaneous" type of equality.  In such a case, the equals and hashCode for this container object will have to use isEquals as part of the container's equals method and toInstant().hashCode() as part of the containers hashCode method.

Answer (score 1):

Read the source code of the two methods:

- The [`isEqual` method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.java#ChronoZonedDateTime.isEqual%28java.time.chrono.ChronoZonedDateTime%29) compares `ZonedDateTime` instances to see if they represent the same instant in time (i.e. equal seconds and equal nanoseconds since epoch).
- The [`hashCode` method of `ZonedDateTime`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/ZonedDateTime.java#2184) is computed by XOR-ing the hashcodes of the `dateTime`, `offset` and `zone`.

There is no way that these two can be expected to be consistent, since they take into account very different properties of the instances.

Comment: Ok, that answers the first part of my question.  Do you happen to know an answer to the second?  For example, would `ZonedDateTime.toInstant().hashCode()` produce a hash-code consistent across `isEqual()`?

Comment: `Instant.hashCode()` computes a hash of the seconds and nanoseconds. Again, simply answered by [reading the source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/Instant.java#1314). Note that `Instant` does not have an `isEqual` method.